# Работа с одинаковыми классами js

Tags: javascript

```js
$(".select_box").click(function () {
    $(this).children('.option_box').toggleClass('open');
});
$('.select_box .option').click(function() {
    var num = $(this).text();
    $('.input_val').val(num);
    $('.number_val').html(num);
});
```

```css
.select_box {
  position: reletiv;
}
.option_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.option_box.open {
    max-height: 300px;
    transition: max-height 0.8s ease-in;
}
.value_tag {
    min-height: 45px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.option_box li {
    padding: 4px 15px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.option_box li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(38, 182, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select_box">
    <div class="value_tag">
        <span class="number_val">1</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
    </div>
    <ul class="option_box">
      <li class="option">1</li>
      <li class="option">2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="select_box">
    <div class="value_tag">
        <span class="number_val">1</span>
        <input class="input_val" type="hidden"  value="">
    </div>
    <ul class="option_box">
      <li class="option">1</li>
      <li class="option">2</li>
      <li class="option">3</li>
      <li class="option">4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Не получается реализовать следующую задачу:
при клике на li с классом option мне нужно что бы подставились значения только в этот div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
$('.select_box .option').click(function() {
    var num = $(this).text();
    $(this).closest('.select_box').find('.input_val').val(num);
    $(this).closest('.select_box').find('.number_val').html(num);
});
```